# prestashop exclude products from product list

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I would like to exclude items that are marked as "online only" from the product list.

The beginning of the product-list.tpl is:

```
<ul id="product_list" class="categorie_product clear">
    {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
        <li class="ajax_block_product ........etc........>
```

Putting in this:

```
<li {if $product.online_only}style="display:none"{/if}>
```

removes the products from the list, but they still take up space in the list. So I'm thinking the only way is to exclude the products that are set to be online only from the foreach itself, but am kinda lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ah, yes I forgot about pagination.
Looks like you have to exclude those products from MySQL query from the get go.

Go to classes/category.php and find function getProducts.

Find `if ($getTotal)` and replace the last line with this:
`'.($id_supplier ? 'AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '').' AND p.online_only = 0');`
This will return the number of NOT (online only) products, so pagination will work correctly.

Right below that you will see the variable $sql.
Replace the last line with this:
`'.($id_supplier ? 'AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '').' AND p.online_only = 0';`
So that only NOT (online only) products are fetched.

It should work. Now you don't need the {continue} I mentioned earlier because only those products that are NOT (online only) are fetched from the database.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick for that part, but the problem still exists though the non-online products dont appear in the page code anymore.

Comment: And so it turns out that the problem is actually in the pagination, which still gets all products from the category and therefor the product list still thinks there are more products -> for example 5 out of the actual 16 are now showing, but the page isnt filled with products from the next "page" so that it would display the wanted 16 per page

Comment: Editing the category.php at the getTotal doesn't seem to have any affect on the product list whatsoever, so I can't say if its the code or something else thats wrong now. What I mean is I tried even deleting the whole section and nothing changed on the product list. I dont have any overrides so it cant be that. Getting weird.. (btw the presta version is 1.4.8.2)

Comment: getTotal just lets Prestashop know how many products there are, so that pagination works correctly. Did you modify the $sql variable as above as well? I have edited this part of category.php before and it worked. So it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is just what I did, but no effect. The part from category.php in its whole:

```
        if ($getTotal)
    {
        $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->getRow('
        SELECT COUNT(cp.`id_product`) AS total
        FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
        WHERE cp.`id_category` = '.(int)($this->id).($active ? ' AND p.`active` = 1' : '').'
        '.($id_supplier ? 'AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '').' AND p.online_only = 0');
        return isset($result) ? $result['total'] : 0;
    }

    $sql = '
    SELECT p.*, pa.`id_product_attribute`, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, i.`id_image`, il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, tl.`name` AS tax_name, t.`rate`, cl.`name` AS category_default, DATEDIFF(p.`date_add`, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).' DAY)) > 0 AS new,
        (p.`price` * IF(t.`rate`,((100 + (t.`rate`))/100),1)) AS orderprice
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product` AND default_on = 1)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl ON (p.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category` AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)($id_lang).')
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)($id_lang).')
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND i.`cover` = 1)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)($id_lang).')
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tax_rule` tr ON (p.`id_tax_rules_group` = tr.`id_tax_rules_group`
                                               AND tr.`id_country` = '.(int)Country::getDefaultCountryId().'
                                               AND tr.`id_state` = 0)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tax` t ON (t.`id_tax` = tr.`id_tax`)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'tax_lang` tl ON (t.`id_tax` = tl.`id_tax` AND tl.`id_lang` = '.(int)($id_lang).')
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
    WHERE cp.`id_category` = '.(int)($this->id).($active ? ' AND p.`active` = 1' : '').'
    '.($id_supplier ? 'AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '').' AND p.online_only = 0';
```

Comment: Right so I tested that on another installation and it worked, what also works is 

WHERE p.online_only = 0 

on the second to last line on the $sql part.

Anycase I must have messed something up in some file on my system, so thanks for the (working) input :)

Comment: Great! Adding "WHERE p.online_only = 0" to both $result and $sql is exactly what I suggested above. If you found my answer helpful, please consider choosing it :)